# why database name must be static?

Tags: android

My question is very simple ! I have seen several applications that define database name(or table name) as a static variable !
why ?

like :

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME   = "database" ;
```

can I define it as a final variable ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly this way you want to say that your `DATABASE_NAME` is not part of every instance of your class, but a part of the class itself. That would mean that each time you declare an instance of your class, each of those classes won't have a copy of that attribute but they will **share** that attribute instead.

Quite logic, this is meant to be a static field so why make an instance of it? And yes, it should be a `final` variable, as it is unlike it will change at execution time.

Answer (score 2):

For convenience. The DB name never changes while the app is running or between instances of the same class - it can only change between app versions. This way if you change the name of your database you won't have to search for it in the entire app - just modify the DATABASE_NAME variable.