# Why database name and version must be static?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Ok here is same question [why database name must be static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127615/why-database-name-must-be-static)
but i know already that why we should declare **database** name static & final.

And i tried to give non static database name into constructor of SQLiteOpenHelper but end up with an error `the field can't be quoted from the static context`

I want to know/find the source code or particular line where it was decided to make those ( database & version ) static.

I looked already https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java but couldn't find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about Java, not about Android sqlite.

When initialising an object instance, constructor is invoked before initialising member fields. The database name is a constructor argument and needs to be initialised when invoking the constructor. When it's static, it's not an instance member but a class member that is initialised earlier when the class is first accessed.

See [Java order of Initialization and Instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23093470/java-order-of-initialization-and-instantiation)